# How to create dynamodb table only if not exists via cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-codepipeline

I know the syntax for creating a dynamodb table on the cli, but how to create it only if doesn't exist? I want to do this via cli because it will be running on CodePipeline in AWS

What are the best options? 
Thanks

Comment: If you're running this within a shell script then can you just test if the table already exists with `aws dynamodb describe-table` before attempting the create? Or invoke the create and ignore a 'table already exists' error.

Comment: CodePipeline fully supports CloudFormation. Why not use that? It will manage create vs. update vs. delete for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below's snippet for shell script, if describe table fails then create new table

```
DB_NAME=table_name

if aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name $DB_NAME 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "DynamoDB Table: $DB_NAME found, Skipping DynamoDB table creation ..."
else 
    echo "DynamoDB Table: $DB_NAME not found, Creating DynamoDB table ..."
    aws dynamodb create-table --table-name $DB_NAME --attribute-definitions AttributeName=LockID,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=LockID,KeyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5
fi
```